# Как поменять php 5.6 на версию 7.0

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache

Как поменять php 5.6 на версию 7.0 (сервер на ОС Ubuntu 16.04.2)

*Дополнено из комментария:* В консоли показывает версию 7.0.3, а на апаче висит 5.6.10

Comment: Пользоваться гуглом, подсказка - фраза "перенос на php 7"

Comment: Ищу на русском языке.

Comment: Установить PHP7, настроить приложения на использование PHP7. Если вкратце. А если подробнее, то пишите, что вы делали и что у вас не получилось.

Comment: Выполнил как здесь - http://php.net/manual/ru/migration71.php В консоли показывает версию 7.0.3, а на апаче висит 5.6.10

Comment: Если у вас код действительно 5.6, а не 5.2 за уши подтянутый до 5.6 - особых проблем возникнуть не должно.

Comment: Вообще-то в Ubuntu 16.04 уже по умолчанию идёт php7. Как у вас оказался php5.6?

Comment: У меня стояла 14.04 с установленным Аначем. Недавно обновил систему до 16.04. А модуль РНР остался старым

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужна новая версия php (7.1.3 ..)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.1
```

Дальше, в apache ты должен переключить модуль.
Настройки модулей расположены в директории /etc/apache2/mods-available. (там появится твой php7.1, а в /etc/apache2/mods-enabled сейчас находится php5.6, ниже команды отключат php5.6 и включат php7.1)

```
sudo a2dismod php5.6
sudo a2enmod php7.1
```

И делаешь рестарт апача

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

P.s. вчера только сам с убунту возился, присматриваюсь) думаю стоит ли его взять в качестве основного сервера.

Comment: спасибо за ответ!, так долго искал а оказалось так просто!

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/ru/install.unix.apache2.php

Отредактируйте ваш httpd.conf, чтобы Apache загружал модуль PHP. Путь в правой части инструкции LoadModule должен указывать на модуль PHP.
For PHP 7: 
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so

После перегрузить apache